# Differential element of current

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

How is the differential current element defined using the surface and volume current density vector (ie J and K)? I understand how it is defined in the 1D case, but cant extend this idea to the 2D and 3D case

Comment: "differential current element" What do you mean by this? You understand that the current flowing through a small surface $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}$ is given by $I = \mathbf{J}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}$, right? A similar relationship can be defined for $\mathbf{K}$ crossing a line.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake Perhaps clearer:   $\mathrm{d}I={\bf J}\cdot\mathrm{d}{\bf A}$?  Also, this sounds like an answer, if you can add some detail.

Comment: @garyp It sounds more like the question is talking about the argument used in the Biot-Savart law, $I\,\mathrm{d}\vec{ell}$, but I don't want to waste time writing an answer on that premise until I'm sure.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake Yes I am talking about that only. I understand Idl, but cant understand the meaning of KdS and JdV